# How can I "provide proper authorization" to the KDE Software Updates program?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, muon-package-manager

I just installed KDE, and every time I run the Software Updates program it says:

> **This operation cannot continue since proper authorization was not provided.**

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Do you have kdesudo or kdesu installed?

Comment: KDE Software Updates use PolicyKit, not `kdesudo`

Comment: Can we get a few more details? When does this error occur? After opening, after checking for updates, after telling them to install? Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry about the misleading comment then. It's been a while since I used KDE. Then it's probably a PolicyKit policy problem. If that hasn't changed, policies can be edit in System Settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earlier : [Ubuntu 11.10 with KDE installed does not prompt for elevation for privileged ops in all apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80545/ubuntu-11-10-with-kde-installed-does-not-prompt-for-elevation-for-privileged-ops)

Few bug reports:

- Muon-updater doesn't ask for password / https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qapt/+bug/833058
- Kubuntu desktop missing dependency on polkit-kde-1 / https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1-gnome/+bug/867737

Do you have the polkit-kde-1 installed ?

The polkit-kde-1:

> PolicyKit-Kde provides a D-Bus session bus service that is used to 
>   bring up authentication dialogs used for obtaining privileges.

Comment: Thanks. `sudo apt-get install polkit-kde-1` and rebooting fixed it.

Comment: I have added that package note to the KDE installing section on the wiki https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE as it needs it so we need to note it.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install polkit-kde-1`

did not fix it for me (Kubuntu 12.10), but this did:

`sudo apt-get -f install`

It also showed that I had a bunch of packages with unmet dependencies.  I had just run a bunch of updates with Muon and rebooted, but apparently it did not pick up all the dependencies.