# Plasma - Discover gets - not authorized message when selected Install

Tags: plasma

Using this thread - none of it worked for me: [How can I "provide proper authorization" to the KDE Software Updates program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103350/how-can-i-provide-proper-authorization-to-the-kde-software-updates-program)

However when I click on Updates then it starts checking for any and shows them. I click on Install and it still shows: This operation cannot continue since proper authorization was not provided.

This used to work and prompt me for password.

I have: Kubuntu 18.04, KDE Plasma Ver: 5.12.7

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` from a terminal. Is that successful? Do you see any messages / warnings / errors while doing so? Then run `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop` in case you've accidentally deleted something that Discover needs. Then, run `plasma-discover` from a terminal to see if things are fixed; if not, the terminal output may provide you with clues.

Answer (score 0):

I corrupted things so badly in that OS.. I went ahead and installed a clean version of Kubuntu 18.04, KDE Plasma Ver: 5.12.7 and built things back as needed.